# Elasticsearch for index array element

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-2.0

Hi i want to search array element from index using elastic search query

```
{
  "name": "Karan",
  "address": [
                        {
                            "city": "newyork",
                            "zip": 12345
                        },
                        {
                            "city": "mumbai",
                            "zip": 23456
                        }]
}}
```

when i am trying to search using match query it does not work

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "address.city": "newyork"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

when i access simple feild like "name": "Karan" it works, there is only issue for array element.

Comment: Can you please show the mapping for the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because nested objects are indexed as separate hidden documents, we can’t query them directly. Instead, we have to use the ***nested query*** to access them:

```
GET /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "eggs" 
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "comments.name": "john"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "comments.age": 28
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
}}}
```

[See the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/nested-query.html)

Comment: yes , this is just a template , and you will need to modify things on your side accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The way i followed..

Mapping :

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "job": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "skills": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Records

```
[{"_index":"jobs","_type":"job","_id":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":{"name":"sr soft eng","skills":[{"value": "java"}, {"value": "oracle"}]}},{"_index":"jobs","_type":"job","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{"name":"sr soft eng","skills":[{"value": "java"}, {"value": "oracle"}, {"value": "javascript"}]}},
```

search Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": {"skills.value": "java"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```